# How can I get the path to my chef logs in Ruby code

Tags: chef-infra

I want to get the string value of the path to wherever my Chef::Log.info is outputting to. I need the value to add functionality to my Ruby code. Is this possible?

Comment: Where do you want to to output i.e, in log or pass to the code. Question is not clear. [ask]

Comment: Theorically the constant `LOG_LOCATION` should point to the right value in chef 13. `Chef::Config['log_location']` should work in chef 12

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get is `Chef::Config[:log_location]` but that will be inaccurate at best since it doesn't know if logging is even enabled or if it's been redirected by other logging handlers (e.g. sending to syslog or the windows event log).